# UserNotifications App Icon Not Loading In Notification iOS 14

Tags: swift, usernotifications, ios14

So I've implemented notifications into my app, however I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but the app icon that displays with the notification doesn't display on my iPhone, it instead shows the default icon! The weird thing is that it works on the simulator, but yeah! Is this a bug? Here's what they look like:

[image: image1 of simulator icon working][image: image2 of iPhone icon not showing][image: image showing I have all icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably occurring because of the caching of app icons.

Firstly, try restarting the device and the issue must be resolved, I know this doesn't feel like a real solution but, it works this occurs due to weird iOS bug in some versions.

If the issue still persists you can

1. Uninstall the app.
2. Restart the device.
3. `Menu` - `Product` - `Clean Build Folder`
4. Clear `Derived Data`.
5. Then run again and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: So I tried uninstalling it, but it didn't seem to work- How do you clean the target?

Comment: I just tried that, but that didn't seem to work either. I also tried deleting all the app icons, running the app, then re-inserting the icons and running again, however the same bug happens!

Comment: Yeah I just tried it again, I uninstalled the app, then cleaned the build folder, then I deleted all the contents of the Derived Data folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Real device, in the simulator the icon was loading from the start!

Comment: There we go! Restarting the device fixed it for me, thank you for all your help!

Comment: There we go, at last. Happy coding.